# Symfony2 Propel validation (UniqueObject) in controller

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, propel

I have a problem with my form validation. Form is manual, without using any types.

Inside my controller I have a validation:

```
$form = $request->request->get('form');
$character_name = $form['character_name'];

$character = new Character();
$character->setName($character_name);

$yamlFile = "../src/Game/PlayerBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml";

$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->addYamlMapping($yamlFile)->getValidator();

$errorList = $validator->validate($character);

if (count($errorList) == 0) {
    $data = array('success' => true);
} else {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'error' => $errorList[0]->getMessage());
}
```

validation.yml:

```
Game\PlayerBundle\Model\Character\Character:
  constraints:
    - Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject:
        fields: name
        errorPath: name
        message: error.unique.character_name
        groups: select_class
  properties:        
    name:
        - NotBlank:
            message: error.not_blank
            groups: select_class
        - Length:
            min: 3
            max: 32
            minMessage: error.length.{{ limit }}.min.name
            maxMessage: error.length.{{ limit }}.max.name
            groups: select_class
        - Regex:
            pattern: '/^[\w-`][\w-` ]{1,30}[\w-`]$/'
            match: true
            message: error.regex
            groups: select_class
```

It's all what I have. Validation still returns no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject` can only be used to check for uniqueness of the properties of a class, so you will need to attach this constraint to a class, not to a string.

https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/blob/2.0/Validator/Constraints/UniqueObject.php#L75

Comment: Yep, I know :P I tried this with Propel model, but it's not working^^

Comment: Can you also show us how you validate your model? Thanks

Comment: I might need more information. It seems to be ok what you have now

Comment: Ehh... I'm stupid xD Validation group was a problem^^

Comment: That's what I was writing now :D. Glad you found the problem ;)

Comment: I have one question more. I can remove validation group from yml file. But the better way will be add this validation group name to the validator. How I can do it?

Comment: Replace `$errorList = $validator->validate($character);` with `$errorList = $validator->validate($character, null, array('select_class'));`. Glad I could help